# How to catch exception from controller (or service) by middleware?

Tags: exception, .net-core, middleware

How do I catch all the exceptions from controllers (or services) in .Net Core WebApi?

My Service

```
    public class MathService : IMathService
    {
       (...)

        public double Divide(int x, int y)
        {
            return x / y;
        }
        (...)
    }
```

My Controller

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        (...)
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<double> Get()
        {
            return _math.Divide(7, 0);
        }
    }
```

My Middleware

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
        }

        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
        {
            var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected

            if (ex is Exception) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = ex.Message });
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
```

Startup Configure

```
            (...)
            app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
            app.UseMvc();
```

This should be enough to catch the exception and return the JSON message with the error right?

What I am missing out?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure middleware is registered first in the pipeline do it can catch everything from downstream.

Comment: Just note that there is a built in exception middleware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#built-in-middleware

Comment: I'm guessing what you're actually looking for is a custom exception handler middleware. If not, in that case you just want to redirect a user to a custom error page, then use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/home/error");` in the configure method of startup

Comment: @Dennis1679 I want to return a json error response, for an API, not a View.

Comment: @anibal In that situation, if an error occurs, the
HTTP 500 status code is more descriptive and useful to a consuming application.
Luckily for you, this is the default behavior when you don’t add error-handling middleware
to your application. Look, in the simplest case, where your whole application serves as an
API to another application, you could probably get away without any error handling
middleware. But in reality, you may want to make sure you log the errors using middleware,
but in any way you certainly don’t need to change the response body in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to catch all exception and map to correct http response code with 
[GlobalExceptionHandler](https://github.com/JosephWoodward/GlobalExceptionHandlerDotNet)